# jaxb marshall to XML document

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

I need to marshall JavaBeans to org.w3c.dom.Element
I can marshall to output stream, but not to XML document.
I wrote following test code:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(String.class);            
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

String xmlRootName = "rootTag";
JAXBElement jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(new QName("", xmlRootName), String.class, "foo bar");
Element element;

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();

m.marshal(jaxbElement, doc);
System.out.println("Document: " + doc);

element = doc.createElement(xmlRootName);
m.marshal(jaxbElement, element);
System.out.println("Element1: " + element);

DOMResult res = new DOMResult();
m.marshal(jaxbElement, res);
element = ((Document)res.getNode()).getDocumentElement();
System.out.println("Element2: " + element);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
m.marshal(jaxbElement, writer);
System.out.println("Writer: " + writer);
```

Output is:

```
Document: [#document: null]
Element1: [rootTag: null]
Element2: [rootTag: null]
Writer: <rootTag>foo bar</rootTag>
```

Looks like marshalling works only to output stream. How to marshall to xml document?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are marshalling the object correctly.  To log the result you need to use the `javax.xml.transform` APIs.  The result you are getting with `System.out.println` is simply the result of `toString` being called on the DOM node which can return anything.

### Java Model

**Foo**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        // Build the Domain Objects
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("Hello World");

        // Create the Document
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        // Marshal Object to the Document
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(foo, document);

        // Perform Operation on Resulting Document
        NodeList elements = document.getElementsByTagName("bar");
        for(int x=0; x<elements.getLength(); x++) {
            System.out.println(elements.item(x).getTextContent());
        }

        // Output Document to System.out
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
Hello World
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><foo><bar>Hello World</bar></foo>
```